# Modifications in my tf.Graph change my NN weights initialization

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

Before starting, I am using *python3.4.6* and *tensorflow1.4.0*.

I am aiming to compare an exact same NN architecture when training in tensorflow under different input pipelines. For this purpose, I want to first ensure that same NN graph gets same initialization weights, regarding the input pipeline previously defined.

I have seen that there exists two PRNGs in tensorflow, the graph one and the operations one. I'm currently doing a `tf.set_random_seed(777)` to set the graph's seed.

In order to make it easy, I post below a couple of codes that differ in the input pipeline and its weights output (a subset of them):

**Code 1**:

```
import tensorflow as tf

g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():

    # Set graph seed
    tf.set_random_seed(777)

    # Input placeholders
    input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 512, 512, 3))
    labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=(None, 1))

    # Dummy placeholder
    # dummy = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)

    # Example Model
    conv1_1 = tf.layers.conv2d(input_x, 8, 3, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='conv1_1')
    conv1_2 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv1_1, 8, 3, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='conv1_2')
    pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv1_2, 2, 2, name="pool1")

    session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=False)
    with tf.Session(config=session_conf) as sess:
        sess.run([tf.local_variables_initializer(), tf.global_variables_initializer()])

        conv1_1_kernels = [v for v in tf.trainable_variables() if v.name == "conv1_1/kernel:0"][0]
        print(sess.run(conv1_1_kernels)[:, :, 0, 0])
```

Output code 1:

> [[ 0.03720146  0.0177983  -0.18485998]
>
> [ 0.22072873 -0.14565685  0.21660429]
>
> [-0.15442888  0.12140495 -0.05090818]]

**Code 2**:

```
import tensorflow as tf

g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():

    # Set graph seed
    tf.set_random_seed(777)

    # Input placeholders
    input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 512, 512, 3))
    labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=(None, 1))

    # Dummy placeholder
    dummy = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)

    # Example Model
    conv1_1 = tf.layers.conv2d(input_x, 8, 3, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='conv1_1')
    conv1_2 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv1_1, 8, 3, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='conv1_2')
    pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv1_2, 2, 2, name="pool1")

    session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=False)
    with tf.Session(config=session_conf) as sess:
        sess.run([tf.local_variables_initializer(), tf.global_variables_initializer()])

        conv1_1_kernels = [v for v in tf.trainable_variables() if v.name == "conv1_1/kernel:0"][0]
        print(sess.run(conv1_1_kernels)[:, :, 0, 0])
```

Output code 2:

> [[-0.20316723  0.01109874 -0.16709594]
>
> [ 0.22850838 -0.10679846 -0.22449632]
>
> [-0.13468848  0.12664327  0.2225503 ]]

These codes define my input pipeline through placeholders and define a simple NN graph. Then we start a `tf.Session` as `sess` to evaluate current weights on first channel of the first kernel in first layer `conv1_1`.

The main difference between **Code 1** and **Code 2** is that we got the `dummy` placeholder commented or not. **I have rerun both codes independently several times and weights are consistent**.

So, does anybody knows how to get same weights on my NN layers regarding if I define the `dummy` placeholder or not? Why tensorflow PRNG depends on a previous placeholder (which does not need PRNG)?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is said in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.7/api_docs/python/tf/set_random_seed):

> If the graph-level seed is set, but the operation seed is not: The system deterministically picks an operation seed in conjunction with the graph-level seed so that it gets a unique random sequence.

Looks like this "deterministic pick" depends on  graph contents.

So to have reproducible results you also need to pass operation-level seed:

```py
import tensorflow as tf


g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():

    # Set graph seed
    tf.set_random_seed(777)

    # Input placeholders
    input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 512, 512, 3))
    labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=(None, 1))

    # Dummy placeholder
    dummy = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)

    # Example Model
    conv1_1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
        input_x, 8, 3, 
        activation=tf.nn.relu, 
        name='conv1_1', 
        kernel_initializer=tf.glorot_uniform_initializer(seed=1)
    )
    conv1_2 = tf.layers.conv2d(
        conv1_1, 8, 3, 
        activation=tf.nn.relu, 
        name='conv1_2', 
        kernel_initializer=tf.glorot_uniform_initializer(seed=2)
    )
    pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv1_2, 2, 2, name="pool1")

    session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=False)
    with tf.Session(config=session_conf) as sess:
        sess.run([tf.local_variables_initializer(), tf.global_variables_initializer()])

        conv1_1_kernels = [v for v in tf.trainable_variables() if v.name == "conv1_1/kernel:0"][0]
        print(sess.run(conv1_1_kernels)[:, :, 0, 0])
```

I just added `kernel_initializer` parameters. They should be added to both scripts.

Comment: Do you know if there exists an equivalent to `tf.set_random_seed()` for the operations seed? I was wondering if there is a way to globally set all operation seeds at once instead of defining them all one by one.

Comment: @FerranParés, I don't know. For me it looks like it doesn't exist, but I'm not sure.

Comment: No worries. I have already opened another question regarding it's existence: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50209774/5234494