# `tf.set_random_seed()` equivalent for operations seed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

Title pretty much explains everything. Do you know if there exists an equivalent to `tf.set_random_seed()` for the operations seed in tensorflow. I'm trying to initialize exactly same weights at two exact NN defined into two different graphs, so I was wondering if there is a way to globally set the operations seed for all operations instead of having to define the seed to each operation one by one (in my case, on the kernel initializer of each layer of the NN --> `tf.glorot_uniform_initializer(seed=777)`).

I have been looking for it but failed on my search. Does anyone knows how to set up the operations seed for all the operations in the graph at once? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation of [`tf.set_random_seed()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/set_random_seed) setting only the graph level seed should achieve what you are looking for:

> If the graph-level seed is set, but the operation seed is not: The system deterministically picks an operation seed in conjunction with the graph-level seed so that it gets a unique random sequence.
>
> To make the random sequences generated by all ops be repeatable across sessions, set a graph-level seed

But you have to remember to call `tf.set_random_seed()` for both graphs individually with the same seed.

But that might still not work, especially if the graphs are executed on different devices (I am not sure about that). A safe option to make sure both graphs are using the same initialization might be to simply initialize one of the two and then just set the variables in the second one to the values of the first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I already use `tf.set_random_seed()` but it does not achieve it. The problem is that, though I have same NN graph defined, tensorflow deterministically picks a operations seed based on complete graph at hand, and I got two different input pipelines on each graph. So, the operations seed is deterministically defined but different on each graph. That's why I'm asking if there exists a global setter of operations seed.

Comment: Yea I thought that might be the case. That is why I wrote the last paragraph. There is no other way to set the random seeds (as far as I know), so I would approach the problem by simply copying the values from the one graph to the other.

Comment: Okey, that should work to ensure both NNs have same weights. However, I can already solve this problem by setting the operations seed on each trainable layer of my NN. The question is more focused on the existence of a simple way to set up the operations seed for all operations defined in the graph. I edit my question to make it clear.